# Confusion about the proof that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, field-theory, finite-fields

$F$  is  a finite field  and  $F^{*}$  is  the  multiplicative  group  of  $F$. Then  $F^{*}$  is  cyclic.

The  method  that  they  use  here  to  prove  it  is  that  if  for  each $d$  such  that  $d| |F^{*}|$ we  can  show  $F^{*}$  has   only  one  cyclic  subgroup  of  order $d$,  then  $F^{*}$  is  cyclic.

Let  $d$  be  a divisor  of  $|F^{*}|$  and  $C$  is  the  subgroup  of  order  $d$. then  every  element  of  $C$  satisfies  the  equation $x^{d} =1$  which  can  have  at  most  $d$  solutions so  $C$  is  the  only  group  of  order  $d$  as  if there  were  any  other  subgroup ,  say ,  $H$  of  order  $d$  then  that  will  have  elements  different  from  that  of  $C$ which  also  will  satisfy  the  equation  $x^{d}=1$ and  thus  implying  that  $x^{d}=1$  has  more  than  $d$  solutions which  is  not  possible.

Now  here  is  my  problem  :  there   are   many  groups  that  have  more  than  $1$  cyclic  subgroups  of  the  same  order  and  all   of  those  elements  of  those  groups  satisfy  the  same   equation . How  does  that  work  there  and  why can  the  same  thing  be  applied   here as  a  contradiction $?$

I  hope  I  have  conveyed  my  problem  clearly.

Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: Isn't the word *finite* in front of field pretty important here?  After all the multiplicative group of nonzero rationals is not cyclic, etc.

Comment: @hardmath: Not really. The word *finite* in front of *subgroup of the multiplicative group* OTOH is crucial. The multiplicative group of nonzero rationals has $\langle -1\rangle$ as its ONLY finite subgroup. Inside $\Bbb{C}$ we have finite cyclic subgroups of any order, consisting of roots of unity. In a finite field, of course, all the nonzero elements are roots of unity.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  I was referring to the omission of *finite* in the title and first paragraph, which claim "the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic".  Thus the counterexample of field $\mathbb{Q}$, whose multiplicative group is not cyclic.

Comment: @hardmath: Ok. Sorry. Apparently I didn't read the question carefully enough.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen:  I'm going to make the edit for the sake of clarity, since the OP implicitly assumes $F^*$ is finite in the second paragraph.  But your comment got me to wondering about the converse, if $F^*$ is cyclic, then field $F$ is finite, which I plan to post as a new Question.

Comment: If $F^*$ ha a cyclic subgroup with $d$ members whenever $d | |F^*| $, this includes the case $d=|F^*|$.

Comment: @hardmath: That has been asked many times, so ... Oh, you already did :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key here is that the finite group is a subgroup of a multiplicative group of a field. In a field $F$ the polynomial $p(x)=x^d-1$ can have at most $d$ zeros. This is because the ring $F[x]$ is a UFD, and each zero $\alpha$ of $p(x)$ gives rise to a linear factor $x-\alpha\mid p(x)$.

OTOH, in a multiplicative group it is perfectly possible for the equation $x^d=1$ to have more than $d$ solutions.

Note that it is not essential for the field to be finite itself as long as the group is finite. The same holds for all fields: A finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of any field is cyclic.