# Is a field with cyclic multiplicative group necessarily finite?

Tags: finite-fields, cyclic-groups

It is a standard result that finite fields have cyclic multiplicative groups (the nonzero elements with respect to field multiplication).

A recent discussion on [this Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434065/confusion-about-the-proof-that-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-is-cyclic) leads me to ask about the converse:

> Is a field $F$ whose multiplicative group $F^*$ is cyclic necessarily finite?

Clearly the biggest a cyclic group can be is countable, and thus $F$ would also be at most countable.

Comment: Does the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$ have cyclic multiplicative group?

Comment: @WilliamStagner:  No, since any generator of that algebraic closure would lie in a simple finite algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$, and thus would generate only that many nonzero powers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  If $F^*$ is infinite cyclic, then $F^*$ is torsion-free, and in particular this means that $F$ has only one square root of $1$.  Thus $F$ has characteristic $2$, and furthermore $F$ can contain no nontrivial finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_2$ (since any such finite extension would give torsion in $F^*$).  Thus $F$ contains a subfield of the form $\mathbb{F}_2(x)$.  But the group of units of $\mathbb{F}_2(x)$ is free of infinite rank (generated by the irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_2$), and in particular cannot be a subgroup of a cyclic group.  This is a contradiction.